# How do I wire Honeywell RTH6500 Thermostat?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, installation

I have an old battery powered HW thermostat using 4 wires (W Y G R). I intend to replace it with a Honeywell RTH6500WF using a 24v power adapter, hook the adapter’s 2 wires directly to the baseplate of the new one as a power source.

The manual of the adapter instructs that I connect one wire to the C terminal & the other to the RC terminal of the baseplate. The R & RC terminals are jumpered by default.

I intend to do:

1. From the incoming wires from the wall is W Y G R , no C
2. Connect the W Y G (jumpered R/RC) of the baseplate with the W Y G R wires from the wall
3. Connect the first wire from the power adapter to C of baseplate & the second wire to the R/RC (jumpered) terminal of the baseplate.

If I connect as above, I find that I will end up connecting two wires to the R/RC terminal, i.e., the R from the wall & the second wire from the power adapter.

Is that Ok or am I doing it wrongly? Please help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This should work, but a bunch of the thermostats have an add-a-wire kit that can turn 4 into 5 logical wires, and that would allow you to hook up the existing transformer C wire on your furnace  and avoid a local AC adapter.

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing wiring at your furnace please?

Comment: I had his problem at a house I no longer own. Honeywell now has a special adapter but my recollection is with a 5+ year old version of that stat is that I needed to remove the R/Rc jumper making it seem as though Rc/C was separate power circuit and R to the rest were dry contacts. This method no longer seems to be supported by Honeywell, which makes me concerned that some hazard was identified.

Comment: I intended to make it work at the thermostat inside, avoid the handler unit outside. Yes, Honeywell has an adapter for the outside unit. True. I was just trying for the easy way out.